# What do web browser engine use to render html?

Tags: api, browser, libraries

I've always been wondering : What librairies/APIs are used by web browser engines (Gecko, WebKit ...) to render images, text, buttons & stuff ?

Think about it, webpages are rendered pixel by pixel identically across operating systems. Yet buttons, drop lists and text look native on most platforms.

Comment: you've answered your own question by talking about WebKit et al.

Beyond that enters the OS and its graphics layer.

Answer (score 2):

The main are

```
Trident (IE and derivats)
Webkit (Safari, Chrome)
KHTML (KDE Konqueror) This was the base for webkit
Presto (Opera)
```

You can read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser_engine

These engines create an object structure of the HTML and then use Components to build the page, the browser engine does not render pixel by pixel  but uses buttons, comboboxes, image elements all of which in them self render to a buffer and then those imagebuffers are collapsed to the screen.

Some engines use the plattforms own components (Trident) other use their own with different skins for different plattforms.

For actual rendering I know IE uses windows controlls and Gecko as you noted uses Cairo.

I assume webkit might use gtk or qt but I am not sure and for opera I have no idea but I assume they use some form of framework or toolkit.

Comment: Sure. But how are buttons, comboboxes and images rendered to the screen ? After some research, i found that Gecko uses Cairo for graphics (rectangle, lines etc.) using their own C++ wrapper over it (Thebes). See those links : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=322938 and http://blog.vlad1.com/2007/12/11/graphics-in-mozilla/